# .ics loading as text i.s.o. calendar

Tags: php, iphone, text, import, icalendar

I wrote some software which generates an .ics file. This can then be downloaded via web.

The PHP part to download looks like this:

```
echo "<a class='button button-medium' href='../calendar/$file_name_ics'>Download .ics file</a>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Sample event of downloaded .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
COMMENT: xxxxx 1.0.13 by xxx
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161201
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161202
UID:20170108T185258Z_xxxxx_FLSjsx3qz1M1ZUhB@xxxxxx.xxx
DTSTAMP:20170108T185258Z
SUMMARY:off day
DESCRIPTION:Check event for correctness!\nxxx\nyyy
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

90% of all calendar imports on iPhone/Android devices and web browsers work fine, but once in a while, I get reports that the downloaded .ics file is displayed on iPhone/Android (never web browser) as text and not offered automatically for integration into the device calendar.

Initially I thought about a device setting which might have been wrong, but now I have a tendency to think of a ...

1. local device setting, but which one and where to change?
2. server side setting (see PHP code for download button above)?
3. .ics format problem?

I'm somewhat stuck.

... edit ...

Here some test page for download: http://www.geohei.lu/icstest.html

This test page is bare minimum. No PHP, just HTML.

Safari on iPhone 6S works.
Safari on 1 iPhone 7 doesn't work, 5 others do work ?!?!
UC browser on any device doesn't work !!!

No clue whether it is the .ics content otr some server HTML, PHP or meta data settings on the server side?